# Consumption tax calculation

Tags: magento2, extensions, tax, magento2.3, tax-calculation

I would need to manage on the Magento 2.3 e-commerce (Community Edition) a tax calculation according to consumption (separate from the VAT calculation that is managed with the Magento Tax Rate Percent Standard).
The tax is a parameter associated with a class of products and is calculated at the time of order based on the quantity of product purchased:
- X products have a consumption tax of a€ per milliliter purchased
- Y products have a consumption tax b of b€ per milliliter purchased
etc ...

This calculated consumption tax has to be shown in the order (at details level, calculated for each purchased product, and at the final total level as a summary of all single calculated taxes), as in the invoice, just for a group of customers. For this reason, it should be managed as a Tax Rule.

Has any of you ever had to handle a similar problem?
Do you know extensions that could facilitate this implementation?

Thank you very much!